# Searching data in the table that have database object

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a client data base that has many values related to it.

Client name
Client address
Client code
Client dob

I need to show the client's name in table and allow user to search the client. I add the records to an array and show in a table.

```
for (Clientes *info in fetchedObjects10)
{
    NSString* dict = info.name;

    [dataArray addObject:dict];
}
```

I also create a filtered array for search. But when I search, how I would know which client is selected? How will get other info of that client?

For example, if I search for A in table then filter array is having only 2 elements. If I select the first item, how do I get that item's additional info like address, code, and dob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per i understand your query. you can do it by two ways:-

1) pull all the database fields in the different array (client,client address,client code,client dob ).
search for the client array. The index it was successful pull the other fields from the array.

2) whenever you find the success in searching for the client. Again search the database with the query

sélect cient_address,client_code,client_dob from tablename where client_id=client;

Use the second method if you lot of data. but at the same time client should be the primary key for it.

Reply if there is some more need or your requirement is different.